# DBlink(s) which one is safer: public link or private link?

Tags: .net, sql, oracle, dblink

I'm trying to think of security problems using private/public dblinks.

You can see what I'm talking about in the picture below

[image]

So, as shown in the picture (right option is public and left one is private) which one do you think is safe?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand the question. private dblink is one only the schema can access. public dblink is a private dblink with a global synonym. which one is safer ? probably the privet one. is that what you ment ?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using private database links and create views for the tables you need to access over a database link.

So, if you have a database db1 with users user1db1, user2db1 and user3db1 that need to access table1 in another database db2, do like this:

1. create a user linksdb1.
2. Let that user own a private db link to db2.
3. Create a view linksdb1.table1 for table1@db2
4. grant user1db1, user2db1 and user3db1 rights to the view.

There are two reasons for this:

- Security.  By doing this you have full control over which users are allowed to access the table over the database link, because they need access to the view.
- Maintainability.  You don't need to include the dblink in the SQL, from user1db1's point of view he is accessing a table named linksdb1.table1, instead of table1@db2.  This way, if you move the table to yet another database, db3, you only need to change the view, not all the SQLs.